# Excel Vba avoid repeated extraction of data

Tags: excel, vba

i have a folder which contains e.g files abc, poi, krf, lss and i have a button that contains an existing code that iterates through the folder and extract data from each files into the excel sheet.

However despite the data being already extracted to the excel sheet, every time i click the button it will still extract data from each files, i would like to avoid that by saving all the filenames in the folder into an array or other methods THEN whenever i press the button , it will compare the "previous file names" inside the folder, if any changes are done to the folder, e.g new file mmn is added into the folder, it will only do extraction on file "mmn" and skip extraction on the rest of the files that were still in the folder.

e.g my folder now currently has 50 files(all with different names) e.g "abc","mmn","lll", i save these 50 file names and then if i click on my button to extract data, it will check whether my folder had any changes happened to it, e.g if it still contains the 50 files(same name as previous,"abc","mmm","lll") , then don't do any extraction because data already exists in the excel sheet.

however, if the files in the folder changed, e.g a new file named "uio" got added in, then i want to only do extraction on "uio" and add the data below the last row that contains data instead of all the files "abc","mmn","lll" and "uio" .

This is my current code, can anyone please let me know how i can modify it to match my description?

Thank you to everyone.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopFiles()

Dim strFolder As String
Dim strDirRef As String
Dim nFiles As Long, i As Long
Dim strFound() As String

strFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\asi\"

strDirRef = Dir(strFolder)
Do While Len(strDirRef) > 0
    nFiles = nFiles + 1

    ReDim Preserve strFound(1 To nFiles)
    strFound(nFiles) = strDirRef
    strDirRef = Dir
Loop

For i = 1 To nFiles
    Debug.Print strFound(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Use a `Dictionary` and use the `Exists` method. Or for longer term, paste these values into a (hidden) worksheet, so they would be available when closing/opening the project.

Comment: @JvdV is it possible for you to further explain to me on how i can use your latter method to solve for my issue?

Comment: If you would put your values into an array/dictionary/collection, they are stored in memory. Upon closing/opening your project (end of your workday or so) these will get lost. Storing them either in your worksheets or external for that matter will ensure they there the next time you open your project. If that doesn't matter, then I suggest a Dictionary (to avoid the `Redim` and usage of `Exists` method)

Comment: @JvdV Yes, i am looking to store them in memory using an array/dictionary/collection, is it possible for you to provide maybe a small snippet of the code, i have tried using dictionary/collection but i have no idea how i can make it work despite reading over and over again about it...

Comment: Small example added below for you to have a go with =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hereby a small snippet on how I would store these in a `Dictionary` object using `Exists` method.

```
Public Dict As Object

Sub Test()

Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\asi")
If Dict Is Nothing Then
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End If

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If Dict.Exists(oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)) Then
        'Skip file
    Else
        'Don't skip file and do something....
        'Add to dictionary for next iteration
        Dict.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile), 1
    End If
Next oFile

Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Dict.Keys)).Value = Application.Transpose(Dict.Keys)

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much! sorry to ask this of you but can i ask of you what does `If Dict.Exists(oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)) Then` means? and is `Dict.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile), 1` adding the files into the dictionary? also how can i use this line `Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Dict.Keys)).Value = Application.Transpose(Dict.Keys)`?  i'm sincerely sorry for bombarding you with questions, but no website could make me understand on how to use dictionary.

Comment: `GetBaseName` method will return the name of your files and the `Dict.Exists` method will check if this name allready is **in** the `Dictionary`. And yes, `Dict.Add` method then **adds** these filenames into the `Dictionary` in case you would run your macro again. Finally, to return all your loaded keys (filenames) from the `Dictionary` we can simply get the full `Array` of keys through `Dict.Keys`, being a horizontal array, we would need to `Transpose` it into a vertical `Array` first to be able to paste it into our `Rezided` range.

Comment: Btw, both [this](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) website and [this](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html) one are two of my go-to sources if it comes to `Dictionaries`. Just figured out you asked the same question yesterday.

Comment: yes... i couldn't understand it. can i please clarify with you once more about the entire coding? Am i right to understand the code as it first creates a Dictionary which is empty, then it iterates through my folder and add the files into the dictionary then if i run the marco once more ,it will iterate through the folder again and check if the dictionary of file names exists in my folder?

Comment: thank you! weirdly it will have an error `object variable or with block variable not set` at the line `If Dict.Exists(oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)) Then` sorry if i am asking too much...  but on the `'skip file` column i wrote `Exit Sub` then `Dont skip do something` line i added my own code, could my code be the reason why it has errors? if so is it ok for me to provide you my code and have a look where might be the error? this is really the last step for me to cross over until i get this done >.< or if possible can i have a private chat with you please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206130/discussion-between-jvdv-and-mzmz).

Comment: Would be nice to finally close this question @mzmz. If the answer helped you, click the checkmark.