# How to update a dictionary?

Tags: excel, vba

I am supposed to iterate through my folder and add the file names to a dictionary, then use the existing dictionary (e.g. 60 files) as a reference for the next macro run.

If my folder doesn't have any changes, so the 60 file names match the dictionary, then do nothing.

If there are changes to the folder, e.g. three new files are added to the folder, then, update the dictionary with the new file names then, "do something" but only to the three new files not the 60 existing files unless any of the 60 existing files got deleted.

The code, despite files being added to the folder, does not update the dictionary, and despite it being the same amount of files, it still "do something".

I have never used a dictionary before in any platform and have no knowledge about it.

Code provided by JvdV 
[Excel Vba avoid repeated extraction of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59783217/excel-vba-avoid-repeated-extraction-of-data/59783522#59783522)

```
Public Dict As Object

Sub Test()

Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\asi")
If Dict Is Nothing Then
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End If

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If Dict.Exists(oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)) Then
        'Skip file
    Else
        'Don't skip file and do something....
        'Add to dictionary for next iteration
        Dict.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile), 1
    End If
Next oFile

Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Dict.Keys)).Value = Application.Transpose(Dict.Keys)

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe close your other question [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59783522/9758194). Would be nice to mention someone wrote this code for you too...

Comment: @JvdV Yes so sorry i should have done that, i have added it in...

Comment: Well, there is the option to upvote helpful answers and if there is an answer that you feel answers your question you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on its left. The sites tour tells you a bit more about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be missing the last file. I tested it and changed this line and it included all the files:

```
Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Dict.Keys) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Dict.Keys)
```

I also added some debug lines to help see what decisions it is making. You can add them too if you want.

```
If Dict.Exists(oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)) Then
    'Skip file
    Debug.Print "E: " & oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile) ' <--- added this
Else
    'Don't skip file and do something....
    'Add to dictionary for next iteration
    Dict.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile), 1
    Debug.Print "A: " & oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile) ' <--- added this
End If
```

---

**Update:**

If you are trying to just get a fresh copy of what files are still there, minus any that have been deleted, then you dont need to use the `Public` dictionary line. You just need this instead:

```
Sub Test_3()

Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, oFile As Object

Dim dictNew As Object
Set dictNew = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\asi")

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If dictNew.Exists(oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)) Then
        'Skip file
        Debug.Print "E: " & oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)
    Else
        'Don't skip file and do something....
        'Add to dictionary for next iteration
        Debug.Print "A: " & oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)
        dictNew.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile), 1
    End If
Next oFile

' clear column A
Range("A:A").Clear

' display only the new files
If UBound(dictNew.Keys) > -1 Then
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(dictNew.Keys) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dictNew.Keys)
Else
    MsgBox "No new files found"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, i see, however my dictionary is still not updating though, the old files are still seen there, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Are you expecting it to remove the files that are not new?

Comment: i am expecting it to be updated to the same as the files in my folder, actually i need it to create a dictionary from the start naming it as "filenames" then iterate through my folder containing files and add the file names in the folder to my dictionary("filenames") then when i run the marco the next time it is supposed to iterate through my folder again, then check whether the files in the folder still exists or has been removed in the folder then update the dictionary accordingly, if there are changes to the folder "do something" if not do nothing. sorry for the long comment...

Comment: Based on my testing, that's what it is doing now that I added the `+ 1`

Comment: Or are you saying that you run it, then delete a file from the folder, and it's still showing in the dictionary?

Comment: yes, files can be added or removed from the folder , i would like to match the file names in the folder to the file names in the dictionary AFTER i "do something" when it realizes that some changes has been done to the folder.

Comment: OK - try the updated code I posted in the answer. (notice I changed the name of the routine so that you can keep your old copy "just in case")

Comment: With the edit, it's kinda exactly the same as I had proposed at first. I ended up confused about what OP actually meant. Anyway +1 for the +1, forgot about that... Didn't think it would be needed with the Dict.Count method.

Comment: @JvdV Yeah, I was a bit confused about what exactly the OP expected as well. (obviously)

Comment: @JvdV - something tells me this isn't going to do exactly what he wants either tho, as there is no need to even use a dictionary object if he just wants an up-to-date list. I guess we'll find out when he posts a new question.

Comment: @JvdV  if possible pls have a look at my newest question... thank you so much... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811462/excel-vba-dictionary-multiple-loops

Comment: @braX if possible please have a look at my newest question... thank you so  much... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811462/excel-vba-dictionary-multiple-loops

Comment: @JvdV sorry but i have no idea how to close my questions

Comment: You have closed this one @mzmz.